# Google Sheets or Excel Function to return date based on value

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have this table in Google Sheets (or excel). The year is the two last digit of my code.

```
           Code                Duration Months
    
  1     AC-26482-17              60          
  2     AC-26482-18              30         
  3
```

I would like to return the date in this format (If no data, just leave blanks).

```
       Code              Duration Months        Start         Expiration 
    
  1   AC-26482-17           60                01/01/2017      01/01/2022
  2   AC-26482-18           30                01/01/2018      01/07/2020
  3
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Are all your dates in the 21st century?

Comment: Hi BigBen, yes, they are!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean you want to add the duration in months to the start date? If so, your sample has the wrong expiration date. 30 months added to 1/1/2018 is not June 1st, but July 1st.

The formula in Excel is

```
=EDATE(C2,B2)
```

[image]

If you also want to calculate the start date from the last two characters of the code, given all dates are in this millennium, then you can use this for the start date:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A2,2)+2000,1,1)
```

[image]

edit: To handle blank cells, you can check with IsBlank()

```
=if(isblank(a2),"",DATE(RIGHT(A2,2)+2000,1,1))
```

Comment: The formula works both in Excel and Google Sheets too @SimonGIS.

Comment: I added a formula to calculate the start date

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just have problem when my cell code is blank it returns me : 1/1/2000

Comment: You haven't defined what you would want to see instead. Do you need the formula in rows where the code is empty?

Comment: I added a variant of the formula for blank cells.

Answer (score -1):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,DATE(IF(RIGHT(A2:A, 2)*1>=40,,20)&RIGHT(A2:A, 2), 1, 1)))
```

[image]

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,DATE(YEAR(C2:C), MONTH(C2:C)+B2:B, 1)))
```

[image]